# r - How to assign a list of results to a list of names

Tags: r

How does one take a list of character values and a list of number values and use the characters as a label. Like if I have a list of 30 numbers and 10 characters how do I insert those characters into the list of numbers with even spacing?

```
a
b
c

1
2
3
4 
5
6
7
8
9
```

turn this into:

```
a
1
2
3
b
1
...
```

The input letters are formatted like:

```
c("a", "b", "c")
```

and the numbers:

```
"x"
"1" 0.56
"x"
"1" 0.45
"x"
"1" 0.44
"x"
"1" 0.67
"x"
"1" 0.29
"x"
"1" 0.02
"x"
"1" 0.13
"x"
"1" 0.15
```

Comment: could you provide the list of numbers and characters via `dput()` or by creating them in the code for ease of reproducibility? Also, it's unclear if you're using the terms like "list" correctly -- what is the `class()` of the input and desired output?

Comment: So the input number's class is "numeric" and the input names are characters.

Comment: OK, great. Please see my answer below and let me know if that's what you wanted. I guessed that you wanted a character vector output.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, I'm unclear on what data types you want for the input and output. I'm taking a guess here:

```
c <-c("a","b","c") # some character

n <- c(1,2,3,4 ,5,6,7,8,9) # some numeric

m <- 1
for(i in 1:length(c)){
  print(c[i])
  print(n[m]); m <- m+1
  print(n[m]); m <- m+1
}
```

> ```
> [1] "a"
> [1] 1
> [1] 2
> [1] "b"
> [1] 3
> [1] 4
> [1] "c"
> [1] 5
> [1] 6
> ```

i.e.

```
m <- 1
a <- character()

for(i in 1:length(c)){
  a <- c(a,(c[i]))
  a <- c(a,n[m]); m <- m+1
  a <- c(a,n[m]); m <- m+1
}
a
```

> ```
> > a
> [1] "a" "1" "2" "b" "3" "4" "c" "5" "6"
> ```

Comment: What is the `c` in `1:length(c)` --is that from a previous version of the question?  Also, would it be better as [`seq_len(c)`](http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/05/16/colon-operator-in-R/)?

Comment: @wibeasley No it's just the name I gave to the input object. I edited the answer to make that more clear. I'm not sure why that would be better, but if it works for you it works for me.

Comment: I gotcha.  I didn't know where `c` was coming from, and if it had a chance of being empty.  If it's empty, the `1:length(c)` would produce the (presumably undesired) `1:0` vector.  While `seq_len(c)` would produce the (presumably desired) empty vector that essentially bypasses the for loop.

Comment: @wibeasley well it seems we taught each other something :)

Answer (score 0):

We can build a matrix and unwrap it:

```
x <- letters[1:3]
y <- 1:9
c(rbind(x,matrix(y,nrow=length(x))))
# [1] "a" "1" "2" "3" "b" "4" "5" "6" "c" "7" "8" "9"
```

Or we could use `split<-` :

```
lx <- length(x)
ly <- length(y)
res <- character(lx+ly)
split(res,c(1,rep(2,ly/lx))) <- list(x,y)
res
#  [1] "a" "1" "2" "3" "b" "4" "5" "6" "c" "7" "8" "9"
```

`c(1,rep(2,ly/lx))` is building the factor that will be recycled, then the original values are assigned to their new positions.